# How to remove name and dtype from output code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics, dtype

I was wondering how to remove the "name" and "dtype: float64" from the output? I am a beginner at Python so I'm not sure how!

I have to find the mean, median, and standard deviation grouped by 3 different categorical variables. I figured out how to do that, but I want to get rid of the name and dtype at the bottom.

My dataframe image is attached along with my code. Thank you in advance!

[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGowi.png)
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mng1j.png)

Here's my code in typed version as well:

```py
print(f"Mean:{df['Depression_Score'].groupby(df['Treatment_Type']).mean()}")
print(f"\nMedian:{df['Depression_Score'].groupby(df['Treatment_Type']).mean()}")
print(f"\nSD:{df['Depression_Score'].groupby(df['Treatment_Type']).mean()}")`
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`to_string`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) like this:

```
df['Depression_Score'].groupby(df['Treatment_Type']).mean().to_string()

#or

print(f"Mean:{df['Depression_Score'].groupby(df['Treatment_Type']).mean().to_string()}")
```